# Motorcycle battery - correct voltage running and stopped?

Tags: electrical, motorcycle, battery

Hopefully a pretty straight forward one: I've been having trouble starting my bike. I checked the voltage on the battery when it was idling and got 12.9. Is this too low?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is a little low, normal voltage should be about 14volts at idle and 12volts with the engine off. However you need to check this with a fully charged battery. That way you can isolate the problem to the battery or the charging system. I might be fine for a while but if you start taxing the electrical system with frequent starts and long term headlight use you might see issues.